# "No source available for SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()" using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, openssl

I'm trying to make a secure connection with SSL.  I downloaded the source code from [the IBM site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/apps/download/index.jsp?contentid=11410&filename=intro-openssl.zip&method=http&locale=) and run the `withssl` file.

I receive an Error Message while debugging:

```
No source available for "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() at 0x3b66a361b0"
```

What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

Comment: There's no code after "following code". Please also try to formatting your question a bit, it is hard to read as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we have the same code (downloaded it from the link you provided, which will not work without minor modifications, adding `SSL_library_init()` should do the trick for newer version).

Make sure the `TrustStore.pem` file is in the same directory as the executable or change the path in the code accordingly.